# How to implement any alerting based on Amazon Insights metrics

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, monitoring

I want to create some kind of alerting (slack/telegram whatever) based on Amazon Insights metrics.

For example I want to push some message when CPU load is more than N% or when QUERY takes more than 0.1 CPU
Such information available in Insights however I have no idea how can I fetch it

[image: How it looks like in Amazon Insights]

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found useful link about Insight API
on official site 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.API.html